# Skip if value exists in database mysql database - pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Is there an `exception` in my `pymysql` insert statement below that I can use here to `pass` on looping if the value already exists?

My code looks like:

```
   try:
       with db.cursor() as cursor:
           sqltld = "INSERT INTO `table`(`colname`) VALUES (%s)"
           cursor.execute(sqltld, (self.url))
           db.commit()
    except:
       print("error INSERTing url")
       db.rollback()
```

Mysql is already enforcing `unique` on the column `colname`

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: I meant via an elif, pymysql, exception e.g. `pymysql.exceptions.IntegrityError`